# Grails Illegal argument constraint exception

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to run [sample](https://grails.org/Simple+Login+Tutorial) grails application.

I have pasted code and exception we are getting due to this code:

```
def constraints = {
    hardiness(inList:["Hardy", "Half Hardy", "Tender"])
    annual(inList:["Annual", "Perennial", "Biennial"])
}
```

Caused exception:

> IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Object field org.User.constraints  to java.lang.Class

It seems constraint field is not configured properly

Can you please let me know possible reason behind this?

Comment: Can you show the source code for your `User` class?

Comment: I looked at that tutorial and I see the problem.  See my answer below.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question.  The code in the published tutorial doesn't work.  The reason why is obvious to folks familiar with the framework but I would not expect a new Grails developer to spot the problem right away and if you don't understand some specific details about what the framework is doing with the `constraints` property, this might be confusing for someone.  I disagree with this question being voted down.

Comment: The problem with this question is that it's a problem with code, but there is no code in the question. Just linking isn't good enough, because some day that link will die, or the code on the tutorial will be updated.

Comment: Thanks for pointing exact reason for code downvote.i have added code which was causing issue.earlier i was not sure of exact reason for this issue

Comment: @Vish thank you. I have tweaked your formatting and voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tutorial is quite old and the syntax there is no longer valid.  The `constraints` property needs to be static...

```
// grails-app/domain/demo/User.groovy
package demo

class User {
    // ...

    // use static here, not def...
    static constraints = {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: may require your more help in coming days :P